# Xamarin.Forms Picker - System.Reflection error

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism, picker

I have a simple picker that binds `Items` dynamically, meaning it changes when a `Switch` is toggled. However, there is an exception error : `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation`  when it comes to binding of the `ItemSource` of the picker when there is currently an item that was selected which `SelectedItem` handles. Is there a way to handle the binding of picker whenever there is a `SelectedItem` that has been picked? Thanks.

**`Picker.xaml`**

```
<Picker ItemSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, 
        Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedItemIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem, it seems like the `SelectedItemIndex` returns a `-1` value so what I did is to throw a `if(_SelectedItemIndex > -1)` inside the property. So here's what happened:

```
private int _SelectedItemIndex ;
public int SelectedItemIndex
{
    get { return _SelectedItemIndex ; }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _SelectedItemIndex , value);
        if(_SelectedItemIndex > -1)
            lblItem = Items[_SelectedItemIndex ].ItemName;
    }
}
```